# Kotlin quadruple, quintuple, etc. for destructuring

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am looking for a clean way to create destructurable objects in-line. `kotlin.Pair` and `kotlin.Triple` cover a lot of use cases, but sometimes there are more objects that are needed to be passed.

One sample use case is RX's `zip` function, where the results of several I/O calls need to be mapped into another object:

```
Single
    .zip(repositoryA.loadData(someId),
         repositoryB.loadData(someId),
         repositoryC.loadAll(),
         repositoryD.loadAll()),
         { objectA, objectB, objectsC, objectsD -> /*some Kotlin magic*/ }
    )
    .map { (objectA, objectB, objectsC, objectsD) -> /*do the mapping*/ }
```

I am trying to figure out what would go in the "some Kotlin magic" part. If there were only 3 repositories, it would be

```
Triple(objectA, objectB, objectsC)
```

Do I need to create a new data class for this, and for any n-tuple case, or is there another way?

Comment: Beyond Triple, you really should consider using a data class anyway. It's unlikely that the data you're sending is adequately modeled by a tuple at that point

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Basics

Let's see how **destructuring** works:

Kotlin defines a convention for this, i.e. `componentX()` `operator` functions are an example of the principle of conventions used in Kotlin in many places. These `componentX()` functions are used by the compiler for the initialization of variables in destructuring declarations.

For example in `Pair<A,B>` these functions look as follows:

```
operator fun component1(): A = first 

operator fun component2(): B = second
```

As you can see these are [`operators`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html), specially handled functions.
These `componentX()` functions can be provided by the developer and will automatically be produced by the compiler for `data` classes. `Pair` also is such a `data` class btw.

### Answer

Thus, just go ahead and use `data` classes whenever you need more than a `Triple`.

For example, a class `MultiComponent` defined as this:

```
data class MultiComponent(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int, val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int)
```

will be compiled to a class with functions `component1()`, `component2()`, ..., `component6()` and can be used in destructuring declarations:

```
val (q, w, e, r, t, z) = MultiComponent(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: This is nice feature of kotlin. I like kotlin more day by day, because most python features are implemented mostly somehow same way. Not exactly same way, so somehow anyway. One pythonism is methods/functions that return many values This is very difficult to implement by java, but quite easy with kotlin by data class.

 data class MultiComponent(objectA:A, objectB:B, objectsC;c, objectsD:D)
 fun someFunction(...):Multocomponent

Answer (score 38):

I found it easiest to just code-gen the n-tuples needed. Use-case was functional extension methods for things like memoization, etc.

```kotlin
data class NTuple2<T1, T2>(val t1: T1, val t2: T2)

data class NTuple3<T1, T2, T3>(val t1: T1, val t2: T2, val t3: T3)

data class NTuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>(val t1: T1, val t2: T2, val t3: T3, val t4: T4)

data class NTuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(val t1: T1, val t2: T2, val t3: T3, val t4: T4, val t5: T5)

data class NTuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(val t1: T1, val t2: T2, val t3: T3, val t4: T4, val t5: T5, val t6: T6)
```

And then generate the necesssary construction-helpers:

```kotlin
infix fun <T1, T2> T1.then(t2: T2): NTuple2<T1, T2>
{
    return NTuple2(this, t2)
}

infix fun <T1, T2, T3> NTuple2<T1, T2>.then(t3: T3): NTuple3<T1, T2, T3>
{
    return NTuple3(this.t1, this.t2, t3)
}

infix fun <T1, T2, T3, T4> NTuple3<T1, T2, T3>.then(t4: T4): NTuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{
    return NTuple4(this.t1, this.t2, this.t3, t4)
}

infix fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> NTuple4<T1, T2, T3, T4>.then(t5: T5): NTuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
{
    return NTuple5(this.t1, this.t2, this.t3, this.t4, t5)
}

infix fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> NTuple5<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>.then(t6: T6): NTuple6<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>
{
    return NTuple6(this.t1, this.t2, this.t3, this.t4, this.t5, t6)
}
```

So I could then do:

```kotlin
val nTuple4 = 1 then 2 then "foo" then "bar"
```

Resulting in:

```kotlin
val nTuple4: NTuple4<Int, Int, String, String>
```

Comment: nice use of infix functions. though at that point could also just define an overloaded `tuple(..)` method. the repeated `then` makes it kinda long and verbose.

Comment: Agreed, but the real value is when you already have a tuple; such as `val nTuple6 = nTuple4 then 7 then 8` — but indeed, a constructor-helper would be helpful too.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your comment @0cd — rereading I believe you were referring to overloading `rangeTo` to use `..` between tuple components? If so, absolutely! The only issue is existing overloads for `Int`, wherein `1 .. 2` would result in a range, rather than an `NTuple<Int, Int>`. You’d have to do `NTuple(1, 2) .. 3`. Otherwise agreed, it’s much less verbose.

Comment: oh, i just meant to say one could create methods like tuple(T1 v1), tuple(T1 v1, T2 v2) and so on. I realized now I shouldn't have used the .. as that could lead to confusion. I like the "then" version that you have too :) .. was just sharing another option.

Comment: @0cd Ah, gotcha :-) A `tupleOf` function with n-ary overloads. Definitely another helpful and more familiar API, like `listOf`, `setOf`, etc.; also a good idea. I had my example tucked away in a common lib I haven't touched in awhile, I'll have to go back and add that if I haven't already.

Answer (score 19):

You can add these `kotlin` classes to your project, they will work exactly like `Pair` or `Triple` but you will be able to pass more objects.

**Quadruple** (lets you pass 4 objects)

```
import java.io.Serializable

/**
 * Created by nalcalag on 09/02/2019.
 * 
 * Represents a quartet of values
 *
 * There is no meaning attached to values in this class, it can be used for any purpose.
 * Quadruple exhibits value semantics
 *
 * @param A type of the first value.
 * @param B type of the second value.
 * @param C type of the third value.
 * @param D type of the fourth value.
 * @property first First value.
 * @property second Second value.
 * @property third Third value.
 * @property fourth Fourth value.
 */
data class Quadruple<out A, out B, out C, out D>(
        val first: A,
        val second: B,
        val third: C,
        val fourth: D
) : Serializable {

    /**
     * Returns string representation of the [Quadruple] including its [first], [second], [third] and [fourth] values.
     */
    override fun toString(): String = "($first, $second, $third, $fourth)"
}

/**
 * Converts this quadruple into a list.
 */
fun <T> Quadruple<T, T, T, T>.toList(): List<T> = listOf(first, second, third, fourth)
```

**Quintuple** (lets you pass 5 objects)

```
import java.io.Serializable

/**
 * Created by nalcalag on 09/02/2019.
 * 
 * Represents a quintet of values
 *
 * There is no meaning attached to values in this class, it can be used for any purpose.
 * Quintuple exhibits value semantics
 *
 * @param A type of the first value.
 * @param B type of the second value.
 * @param C type of the third value.
 * @param D type of the fourth value.
 * @param E type of the fifth value.
 * @property first First value.
 * @property second Second value.
 * @property third Third value.
 * @property fourth Fourth value.
 * @property fifth Fifth value.
 */
data class Quintuple<out A, out B, out C, out D, out E>(
        val first: A,
        val second: B,
        val third: C,
        val fourth: D,
        val fifth: E
) : Serializable {

    /**
     * Returns string representation of the [Quintuple] including its [first], [second], [third], [fourth] and [fifth] values.
     */
    override fun toString(): String = "($first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth)"
}

/**
 * Converts this quintuple into a list.
 */
fun <T> Quintuple<T, T, T, T, T>.toList(): List<T> = listOf(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
```

Answer (score 17):

In contrast to Scala, Kotlin does not have n-tuples for values higher than 3 defined. You've correctly identified `Pair` and `Triple`.

Kotlin favors using data classes for these use cases, according to [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/migrating-tuples/). So yes, you'll have to define a data class in order to do what you want, there is no `Quadruple`. I'd personally argue that defining your own data class is more clear, and will end up being compiled and used the same way a hypothetical `Quadruple` would anyway, under the covers.

As for destructuring data classes, Kotlin supports that as well:

```
data class Thingy(val a: String, val b: String, val c: String, val d: String)
val t = Thingy("A", "B", "C", "D")
val (aa, bb, cc, dd) = t
```