# Why do we have functions that named componentN in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I've just looked at `Kotlin` [standard library](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Arrays.kt) and found some strange extension-functions called `componentN`  where N is index from 1 to 5.

There are functions for all types of primitives. For example:

```
/**
* Returns 1st *element* from the collection.
*/
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun IntArray.component1(): Int {
    return get(0)
}
```

It looks curiously for me. I'm interested in developers motives. Is it better to call `array.component1()`  instead of `array[0]` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin has many functions enabling particular features by convention. You can identify those by the use of the `operator` keyword. Examples are delegates, operator overload, index operator and also **destructuring declarations**.

The functions `componentX` allow destructuring to be used on a particular class. You have to provide these functions in order to be able to destructure instances of that class into its *components*. It’s good to know that `data` classes provide these for each of there properties by default.

Take a data class `Person`:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

It will provide a `componentX` function for each property so that you can destructure it like here:

```
val p = Person("Paul", 43)
println("First component: ${p.component1()} and second component: ${p.component2()}")
val (n,a) =  p
println("Descructured: $n and $a")
//First component: Paul and second component: 43
//Descructured: Paul and 43
```

Also see this answer I gave in another thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46207340/8073652

Answer (score 7):

These are [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and they're very convenient in certain cases.

```
val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val (a1, a2, a3) = arr

print("$a1 $a2 $a3") // >> 1 2 3
```

---

```
val (a1, a2, a3) = arr
```

is compiled down to

```
val a1 = arr.component1()
val a2 = arr.component2()
val a3 = arr.component3()
```