# Create collection from another one in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to take certain element from a collection to create another one.

Example I have a list created from this object

```
Student (Id, Code, FirstName, LastName, Age, Birthday)`
```

and I want to create a new collection from my first one that contains certain fields example

```
NewStudent(FirstName, LastName, Age)
```

I tried using `map`, `filter` but I can't get the result right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` works fine for this scenario:

```
data class Student(val id: Int, val code: String, val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int, val birthday: String)
data class NewStudent(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int)

val students = listOf(
   Student(1, "A", "1F", "1L", 11, "1/1/2000"), 
   Student(2, "B", "2F", "2L", 12, "1/2/2000"),
   Student(3, "C", "3F", "3L", 13, "1/3/2000")
)

val newStudents = students.map { student -> 
    NewStudent(student.firstName, student.lastName, student.age) 
}
```

Comment: I didn't know we could use it that way more than two hours I try different solution ! thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [kabuko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197889/8073652) but would like to add an alternative usage of `map`:

It's possible to [destructure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-in-lambdas-since-11) objects (of `data` classes [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979638/8073652)) even inside a lambda, such as the one passed to `map`:

```
val newStudents = students.map { (_, _, fn, ln, age, _) ->
    NewStudent(fn, ln, age)
}
```

The [underscores](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11) indicate the properties that are irrelevant for the mapping. This is a more readable solution imho.

Comment: Not all objects can be destructured. Only instances of a data class or instances of other classes which implement componentN(). Otherwise good point.

Comment: Good point, I took it for granted that he’s using data classes. Thank you.