# Can't use Destructuring declaration

Tags: kotlin

I have a class `Person`:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

I want to use Destructuring declaration with `Parent` like this:

```
val (name, age) = Person("name", 22)
```

but I get this error:

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type Person must have a 
>   'component1()' function  Destructuring declaration initializer of type
>   Person must have a 'component2()' function

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We need to declare `Person` as **data** class.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

it wasn't very clear in the docs but for official ref:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#example-returning-two-values-from-a-function

from  [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) comment:
if for some reason someone can't use data class it's not mandatory. You can declare the functions `component1()` and `component2()` in any class.

Comment: It's not mandatory to declare it as a data class. You can declare the functions `component1()` and `component2()` in any class.

Comment: yes, but the whole point of using Destructuring declaration is to have a concise code, and using data classes is the easiest way.  
but if for some reason someone can't use data class they can resort to `component1()` and `component2()` solution

Comment: That's exactly my point. You don't _have_ to use a data class if that's not appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

It's very helpful if you simply let the IDE do some work for you. Here are the suggestions given by IntelliJ IDEA that help to fix the error:

[image]

It basically lists all *alternatives*: `data` class is probably the easiest one. You can also create the corresponding `componentX` functions manually, which are otherwise automatically generated for `data` classes. In this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979638/8073652), I gave some information on this kind of function.

As to your example, I'll show how to provide the `componentX` functions by using extension functions. This approach is especially useful whenever you're working with classes that you cannot modify yourself. It's that simple:

```
private operator fun Person.component1() = name
private operator fun Person.component2() = age
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use a data class since data classes automatically declare `componentN()` functions ([see the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#example-returning-two-values-from-a-function)).

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
val (name, age) = Person("name", 22) // OK
```

Sometimes you might not have access to the source code of a class you want to allow destructuring, so if for any reasons you are not allowed to use data classes, you can provide the `componentX` functions (`component1` and `component2` in this case) by using extension functions.

```
operator fun Person.component1() = name
operator fun Person.component2() = age
```